# "Could not connect to any X display" with gnuplot (Ubuntu for windows)

Tags: display, environment-variables, qt, gnuplot

I have installed the Ubuntu extension for Windows, but I run into troubles when I want to use gnuplot...
I am just trying to plot a simple data file, but I get the following error :

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-julien_barbaud'

qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 

Could not connect to any X display.

Could not connect to existing gnuplot_qt. Starting a new one.

QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to
'/tmp/runtime-julien_barbaud'

qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 

Could not connect to any X display.
```

As you may guess, I am not veryfamiliar with this problem. Is there Something I should set up in my environment to fix this ?

EDIT: after the suggestion in comments, I tried to use `set term postscript`. The output is different, but still no plot...

[image: plot output after set term postscript]

And after trying `set term png`, the plot command gives me this:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're not running under an X window environment. Perhaps you should install `gnuplot-nox - Command-line driven interactive plotting program. No-X package`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I did install gnuplot-nox (`sudo apt install gnuplot-nox`) before trying to run the programm. I also installed gnuplot-qt right after

Comment: What is the output of `show term` (at the gnuplot prompt)? In the absence of an X server, you may need to set the terminal type to something that writes directly to file e.g. `set term postscript` or `set term png`

Comment: I tried `set term png`. I still don get any plot but the output is different : I get `PNG

(բ    IENDB\`gnuplot>` Postscript is not doing better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve my problem by downloading Xming on my Windows system, so that linux can access X11 
The qt terminal works well in this condition.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: By `"downloading Xming on my Windows system"` you mean you're dual-booting windows + ubuntu and you installed Xming on your windows partition? Or you're using Ubuntu on wsl and by Windows you mean your host OS?

Comment: @toinetoine I was in the latter situation, using wsl

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
libmali-xlnx
libmali-xlnx-dev
packagegroup-petalinux-x11-dev
```

in `rootfs` configure.
Then execute

```
killall Xorg
```

(no need when running `Xorg` for the first time).
Finally run

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/Xorg -depth 16&
```

and then run the qt project.