# Error: Could not connect to any X display [Unable to run wireshark on Ubuntu WSL]

Tags: networking, qt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wireshark

I installed Wireshark in my Ubuntu for Windows WSL following [these steps](https://itsfoss.com/install-wireshark-ubuntu/).

 It's installed correctly as `wireshark --help` and `wireshark --version` work fine.

But upon running wireshark with command `wireshark` it throws an error:
[error can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIUFB.png).

I tried solving it using answers from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106465/could-not-connect-to-any-x-display-with-gnuplot-ubuntu-for-windows), but installing Xming on my Windows system also didn't help. Or perhaps I am not doing it right way.

Please someone suggest some way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using these two commands resolved the issue for me

sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common

sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255644/why-doesnt-wireshark-detect-my-interface